# How to programatically close a view with Composite?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin can open a view with a CTabFolder.I want to close the view when the tabPage closed.
So I added a DisposeListener to the Composite of the tabPage :

```
        composite.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
        @Override
        public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {

        }
    });
```

But I have no idea how to close the view.

Comment: `IWorkbenchPage.hideView`

Comment: IWorkbenchPage.hideView need  a param  --  IViewPart view . How can I get it?

Comment: `IWorkbenchPage.findView`